# custom home launcher

Tags: launcher

I am looking to make a custom home launcher.
BEWARE: I have 0% knowledge of how this is done.

So I own an lg esteem and a Sonyericsson xperia arc.
I love the 4.3" screen of my esteem but I love the launcher of my xperia arc. Can I just swap the png's and animations from my arc to my esteem and recompile them or is there more to it than this?

oh and the launcher for the arc is 890kb and my esteems launcher size is 7mb. Why such a large difference in size.

Answer (score 2):

You should check for the answer in the sample example which comes along the adt. They might help you in getting the right launcher.